# Error assigning to an an element in an array of BigInteger

Tags: java, biginteger

This is my code.  It shows an error when I create an array of `BigInteger` and try to assign a value.

```
package test;
import java.math.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BigInteger[] coef =  new BigInteger[78];
        int a=24;
        coef[a]=676557656534345345654645654654645645645645665656567; // Error comes here why
        System.out.println(coef[a]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Coef Is that object i suppose

Comment: `676557656565656567` is a primitive, because it is no object (I suppose it's a `long`). If you want to assign a `BigInteger` there, you have to instantiate a new one using `BigInteger.valueOf()`.

Comment: It is not a long , Long stands for 9 digit integer values only

Comment: Vote up my question then if it is a gud edit

Comment: Java `int` is a little over 9 decimal digits (31 bits plus sign); `long` is almost 19 digits (63 bits plus sign). @GiantTree Java `long` requires explicit suffix, unlike C and C++ where a decimal literal too large for `int` is automatically `long` or `long long`.

Comment: @VaibhavChhabra what happened did I missed any thing in answering the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**KEEP IN MIND ALWAYS**

All numbers greater then `2147483647` will not be allowed as input because int range is `-2147483648` to `2147483647` (Never forget it).
If just in case your output is greater than the limit it will reverse and to its lowest value i.e `-2147483648`.

I recommend that you use:

```
coef[a]=new BigInteger("324576565343453456546456546546456456456455643671");
```

All important functions are in `java.lang.Math` class and you can perform arithmetic operations by passing a string to it.

Answer (score 2):

Java have static types and the auto boxing is only enabled for the wrappers of primitive types, like `int` to `Integer`, but not for `BigInteger`. You will have to do

```
new BigInteger("676557656534345345654645654654645645645645665656567")
```

explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

First of all number grater then `2147483647` will not be allowed as input because `int` range is `-2147483648 : 2147483647`. if your your output is grater than this number it will automatically reverse and to its lowest value i.e `-2147483648`.

For bit number to operate with `BigInteger` take the number as `String`.

And as your problem I would suggest to use

```
coef[a]=new BigInteger("676557656534345345654645654654645645645645665656567");
```

As it gives you all relevant methods from `java.lang.Math` you can perform arithmetic operation by passing string in it..[check this document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

I have made Fabonacci series which give a huge output when a big number is passed to it....

Have a look at [Fabonacci series on my GitHub](https://github.com/mohit008/Java-Concepts/blob/master/src/math/Fabonacci.java)

Hope it helps you!!

Comment: An `int` *computation* that exceeds 2^{31}-1 wraps around, but a source literal is simply rejected. `long` and floating-point literals can be larger numerically, but none can exactly represent the desired value.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigInteger[] coef = new BigInteger[78];
        int a = 24;
        coef[a] = new BigInteger("676557656534345345654645654654645645645645665656567");
        System.out.println(coef[a]);
    }
```

Comment: Please include more in your answer than just the fixed code. Explain what you've changed, and why.